# último espaço de um vetor não está sendo lido em C

Tags: c, array

escrevi um código em C para contagem de vogais em um input e encontrei um jeito de resolver de certa forma o problema, mas gostaria de saber o pq isso resolveu e o pq do último espaço do vetor (vog[4]) não ter sido lido

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

int i, tamanho, qtd;
char j[30], vog[5], caractere;

vog[0] = 'a';
vog[1] = 'e';
vog[2] = 'i';
vog[3] = 'o';
vog[4] = 'u';

printf("Digite uma palavra ou frase para saber a quantidade de vogais: ");
fgets(j, 30, stdin);

tamanho = strlen(j);
qtd = 0;

for (i=0;i<tamanho;i++){
    caractere = tolower(j[i]);
    if (caractere == vog[0]){
        printf("vogal '%c' encontrada na posição %d\n", vog[0], i+1);
        qtd++;
    } else if (caractere == vog[1]){
        printf("vogal '%c' encontrada na posição %d\n", vog[1], i+1);
        qtd++;
    } else if (caractere == vog[2]){
        printf("vogal '%c' encontrada na posição %d\n", vog[2], i+1);
        qtd++;
    } else if (caractere == vog[3]){
        printf("vogal '%c' encontrada na posição %d\n", vog[3], i+1);
        qtd++;
    } else if (caractere == vog[4]){
        printf("vogal '%c' encontrada na posição %d\n", vog[4], i+1);
        qtd++;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

    printf("A quantidade total de vogais é de: %d", qtd);

    return 0;
}
```

depois que eu mudei o vetor de vog[4] para 6 espaços ao invés de 5 o problema desapareceu, e nesse caso, consegui fazer com que a letra U fosse levada em consideração, mas por que isso resolveu?

Comment: não entendi o que escreveu. O vetor tem 5 itens. Se fossem 4 não teria lugar para 5 vogais. `vog[4]` é um `char` e não um vetor

Answer (score -1):

São 5 vogais e assim o vetor deve ter 5 letras. Entenda que a noção de string em `C` é uma sequencia de caracteres terminada por `0`, o popular `NULL`, então há maneiras possivelmente mais simples de escrever isso. Vou mostrar 2 exemplos porque é uma tarefa comum em programas para iniciantes.

#### sobre o programa original

Considere que toda vez que rodar seu programa vai executar isso

```
    vog[0] = 'a';
    vog[1] = 'e';
    vog[2] = 'i';
    vog[3] = 'o';
    vog[4] = 'u';
```

e depois para toda letra vai rodar isso

```
        caractere = tolower(j[i]);
```

E note que

```
        if (caractere == vog[0])
        {
            printf(
                "vogal '%c' encontrada na posição %d\n",
                vog[0], i + 1);
            qtd++;
        }
        else if (caractere == vog[1])
        {
            printf(
                "vogal '%c' encontrada na posição %d\n",
                vog[1], i + 1);
            qtd++;
        }
        else if //...
```

O código para todas as opções é o mesmo, mudando apenas o índice da vogal. Por sorte são `5` e não `500` ou seu programa ia ficar bem longo...

#### EXEMPLO 1

```
    const char vogal[]     = "aeiouAEIOU";
    size_t     cv          = strlen(vogal);
    char       palavra[30] = "aeiouAEIOUXYZ";
    size_t     tamanho     = strlen(palavra);
    size_t     qtd         = 0;
```

Usando assim não precisa do código para converter as letras toda vez DENTRO do loop. Isso também não estava bom.

E esse loop

```
    // para todas as letras da palavra
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
    {
        // veja se eh uma vogal
        for (int j = 0; j < cv; j++)
        {
            if (palavra[i] == vogal[j])
            {
                printf(
                    "    '%c' encontrada na pos %llu\n",
                    vogal[j], i + 1);
                qtd++;
                break;  // acabou com essa letra
            }
        }
    }
```

faz a mesma coisa que o original mas é mais simples de ler. No fundo são dois loops: para cada letra procura por uma das vogais. E não precisa ficar repetindo o código para cada vogal.

O programa todo:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char vogal[]     = "aeiouAEIOU";
    size_t     cv          = strlen(vogal);
    char       palavra[30] = "aeiouAEIOUXYZ";
    size_t     tamanho     = strlen(palavra);
    size_t     qtd         = 0;

    // printf(
    //     "Digite uma palavra ou frase para saber a "
    //     "quantidade de vogais: ");
    // char* p = fgets(palavra, 30, stdin);
    // if (p == NULL) return -1;
    printf(
        "Total de %llu letras na frase \"%s\"\n\n", tamanho,
        palavra);

    // para todas as letras da palavra
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
    {
        // veja se eh uma vogal
        for (int j = 0; j < cv; j++)
        {
            if (palavra[i] == vogal[j])
            {
                printf(
                    "    '%c' encontrada na pos %llu\n",
                    vogal[j], i + 1);
                qtd++;
                break;  // acabou com essa letra
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nTotal de vogais = %llu\n\n", qtd);
    return 0;
}
```

Note que enquanto está testando pode achar muito mais conveniente usar constantes, como

```
    char       palavra[30] = "aeiouAEIOUXYZ";
```

ao invés de ficar digitando letrinhas toda vez que for testar. E note que é melhor escrever a string que foi lida. Isso dá a segurança de que o programa está usando o que você acha que está usando e faz seu programa se testar sozinho.

#### saída do exemplo

```
Total de 13 letras na frase "aeiouAEIOUXYZ"

    'a' encontrada na pos 1
    'e' encontrada na pos 2
    'i' encontrada na pos 3
    'o' encontrada na pos 4
    'u' encontrada na pos 5
    'A' encontrada na pos 6
    'E' encontrada na pos 7
    'I' encontrada na pos 8
    'O' encontrada na pos 9
    'U' encontrada na pos 10

Total de vogais = 10
```

#### Exemplo 2

Em `C` uma string é um ponteiro. base + deslocamento. Ao declarar por exemplo

```
    char       palavra[30] = "aeiouAEIOUXYZ";
    char*      pp = palavra; // endereco da primeira letra
```

O compilador vai reservar espaço para 30 `char` e colocar o endereço disso em `palavra`. E vai colocar os valores especificados na inicialização a partir desse endereço. E acrescentar um zero ao final, logo depois do `Z`.

E, por exemplo, se acessa a posição 3 do vetor como base + deslocamento: a base é o endereço de início, `palavra`, e o deslocamento é `3`, e assim se escreve *(pp + 3) para ter o mesmo efeito de palavra[3]. Entender isso é essencial em `C`, `C++` e em especial em Assembler.

Sendo assim pode trocar o loop por algo como

```
    // para todas as letras da palavra
    char* pp = palavra; // endereco da primeira letra
    while (*pp != 0)
    {   // veja se eh uma vogal
        for (size_t pos = 0; vogal[pos] != 0; pos+=1)
        {
            if ( *pp == vogal[pos] )
            {
                printf(
                    "    '%c' encontrada na pos %llu\n",
                    *pp, 1+pos);
                qtd++;
                break;  // acabou com essa letra
            }
        }
        pp += 1; // avanca a palavra
    }
```

Que é o mais comum em `C`. Podiam claro ser dois loops `while`, mas como precisa da posição para mostrar o valor no `printf` então o `for` é mais esperto.

`*pp++`  é o mais comum em `C` para incrementar o ponteiro, mas como precisa do valor da letra dentro do loop o incremento fica para o fim do `while`

#### o código completo (2)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char vogal[]     = "aeiouAEIOU";
    size_t     cv          = strlen(vogal);
    char       palavra[30] = "aeiouAEIOUXYZ";
    size_t     tamanho     = strlen(palavra);
    size_t     qtd         = 0;

    // printf(
    //     "Digite uma palavra ou frase para saber a "
    //     "quantidade de vogais: ");
    // char* p = fgets(palavra, 30, stdin);
    // if (p == NULL) return -1;
    printf(
        "Total de %llu letras na frase \"%s\"\n\n", tamanho,
        palavra);

    // para todas as letras da palavra
    char* pp = palavra; // endereco da primeira letra
    while (*pp != 0)
    {   // veja se eh uma vogal
        for (size_t pos = 0; vogal[pos] != 0; pos+=1)
        {
            if ( *pp == vogal[pos] )
            {
                printf(
                    "    '%c' encontrada na pos %llu\n",
                    *pp, 1+pos);
                qtd++;
                break;  // acabou com essa letra
            }
        }
        pp += 1; // avanca a palavra
    }
    printf("\nTotal de vogais = %llu\n\n", qtd);
    return 0;
}
```

A saída é claro a mesma

Comment: não entendi porque sua resposta recebeu um voto negativo

Comment: Alguns "zeladores" pelo SOpt negativam logo em seguida qualquer coisa que eu escreva. É o comum. Um pouco infantil, mas é comum. Respondi a pergunta. Apresentei 2 exemplos de código para uma questão que sempre confunde iniciantes e ainda deixei um exemplo da saída do programa e uma discussão curta sobre tudo.

Comment: E já são dois votos agora, no mínimo. Uma contagem normal seria 4.